# accourding to room availibility i want to show available in calander

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<script>
events: [{
          title: 'Available',
          start: new Date(y, m, d),
          backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
          borderColor: "#f56954" //red
            }],
</script>
```

in the database table, there are some field like check-in date check out date and room_type_id according to this I want to display availability in the calendar

Comment: so where is the model [query] related code to fix this or to get this? what did you do so far to get that ?

Answer (score -1):

if events is an array of room, you can iterate through it:

```
const events = [{
          title: 'Available',
          start: new Date(y, m, d),
          backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
          borderColor: "#f56954" //red
            }],
const availableRooms = events.filter(el => el.title === "Available")
if(availableRooms.length === 0){ // It means that no rooms are available
    const unavailableRooms = events.filter(el => el.title === "Unavailable")
    {...}
} else { // Many/all rooms are available
    {...}
}
```